# RXJava - combineLatest without losing any result

Tags: java, rx-java

I want to combine two observables, one emits n items and the other one only 1.

`combineLatest` will wait until both observables have at least emitted one item and then combines the latest emitted items until both observable have finished. Consider following chronologically order:

- Observable A -> emits result A1
- Observable A -> emits result A2
- Observable B -> emits result B1

`combineLatest` will only combine result 2 of observable 1 with result 1 of observable 2 (can be tester here easily: http://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest).

**What I need**

I need to combine ALL items of two observables, no matter which one is faster. How can I do that?

Result should be (always, independent of which observable starts emitting items first!):

- A1 combined with B1
- A2 combined with B1

Comment: Do you mean that you want all permutations of some sequence `a`, with sequence `b`? Or do you want to zip them? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html

Comment: all permutations... One observable only emits 1 item, the other n items and I want to get n combinations (all n items, each one combined with the 1 item)

Comment: I adjusted my example to make that more clear...

Comment: May be try chaining `startWith` operator in your Observable 2, so that you will not lose any values. Then you will get like, A1 - Empty, A2- B1.. Then all subsequent emissions will merge with latest one from other observable.

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I ran into this same issue. Here's my stab at it. First, the non-working version:

```
    Observable<Integer> emitsMany = Observable.range( 1, 10 )
            .concatMap( i -> Observable.just( i ).delay( 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS ))
            .doOnNext( i -> System.out.println( "produced " + i ));

    Observable<Boolean> emitsOne = Observable.just( true )
            .delay( 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
            .doOnNext( b -> System.out.println( "produced " + b ));

    Observable.combineLatest(
            emitsMany, emitsOne,
            ( i, b ) -> "consumed " + i + " " + b )
    .blockingSubscribe( System.out::println );
```

Sure enough, the first couple emissions from `emitsMany` get dropped:

```
produced 1
produced 2
produced 3
produced true
consumed 3 true
produced 4
consumed 4 true
. . .
```

I think here's the fix.. First we need to wrap `emitsOne` into something that will continue to return the value previously observed without delay. I don't know of an operator that does this, but `BehaviorSubject` does the job.

Next we can use `concatMap` with a nested `take(1) Observable`:

```
    Observable<Integer> emitsMany = Observable.range( 1, 10 )
            .concatMap( i -> Observable.just( i ).delay( 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS ))
            .doOnNext( i -> System.out.println( "produced " + i ));

    Observable<Boolean> emitsOne = Observable.just( true )
            .delay( 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS )
            .doOnNext( b -> System.out.println( "produced " + b ));

    BehaviorSubject<Boolean> emitsOneSubject = BehaviorSubject.create();
    emitsOne.subscribe( emitsOneSubject::onNext );

    emitsMany.concatMap( i -> emitsOneSubject
            .take( 1 )
            .map( b -> "consumed " + i + " " + b ))
    .blockingSubscribe( System.out::println );
```

We now get all the combinations:

```
produced 1
produced 2
produced true
consumed 1 true
consumed 2 true
produced 3
consumed 3 true
produced 4
consumed 4 true
produced 5
consumed 5 true
produced 6
consumed 6 true
produced 7
consumed 7 true
produced 8
consumed 8 true
produced 9
consumed 9 true
produced 10
consumed 10 true
```

Answer (score 0):

Note this is untested:

Create a [ReplaySubject](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/ReplaySubject.html) from observable sequence `a`. For each value that emits on sequence `b` combine that value with the replay subject to create a new observable of [Pair](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html)`<A, B>`. Flat map these observables together and return that as the result.

```
public static <A, B> Observable<Pair<A, B>> permutation(
    Observable<A> observableA, 
    Observable<B> observableB, 
) {
    ReplaySubject<A> subjectA = ReplaySubject.create();
    observableA.subscribe(subjectA::onNext);
    return observableB.flatMap(b -> subjectA.map(a -> Pair.of(a, b)));
}
```

Comment: I'll try this... I actually want a function that supports sequential execution of an arbitrary number of items... I've written a function for this that works, but it's just not beautiful and not really the rx java...